# How to say that something is like nothing or not comparable to other?

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

How can I say that something is not comparable, or "nothing" in comparison to the other?

For example, in case of two rivals in a battle:

> Comparing to my power level, your power level is nothing!
>
> 貴様{きさま}のパワーさは、僕｛ぼく｝のパワーさより (Don't know how to end the sentence) ！

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [various ways to express this](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E8%B6%B3%E5%85%83%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%E5%8F%8A%E3%81%B0%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84), but here are the most useful ones.

> - お前のパワーは僕のパワーとは比べものにならない！
> - お前のパワーは僕のパワーとは比較にならない！
> - お前のパワーは僕のパワーの足元にも及ばない！

Notes:

- A person who might say 貴様 usually does not say 僕. "貴様 and 俺" or "お前 and 僕" are the natural combinations.
- パワー is a noun itself, so you don't need to attach さ to nominalize it. (You can at least say パワフルさ because パワフル is a (na-)adjective, but it's too roundabout in this case.)

Comment: ... I didn't catch that he used "さ"  -_-;

Comment: Thanks! (Also I've thought that nominalizing this is ok beacuase I've misunderstood this in the Ginyu Tokusentai song from DBZ: "...Saikyou no pawaa sa...". I possibly replaced the particle with the nominalizing suffix)

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of ways you could end that sentence, and there are other speech patterns that might work for you if you actually want to express the literal idea of "incomparable".

I think the most natural way to finish the sentence as you have written it would be:

> 「貴様{きさま}のパワーは、僕{ぼく}のパワーより**小{ちい}さい。**」

you might also choose words like **弱{よわ}い** or a phrase like **大{たい}したことじゃない** or **なんてこともない**

However, I am not actually sure that a native speaker would choose to use the "より" method of comparison, when talking specifically about one person's power being incomparable to their own or another person's... It might be more (grammatically) natural instead to say something like

> 「貴様{きさま}のパワーは、僕{ぼく}のとは比{くら}べられない。」

Comment: Thanks! The last example also seems more natural for me.